# Accessing self inside GCD block in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

When I access a self object inside a view animation API like this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10 animations:{    
    // accessing self object.
}];
```

will this lead to retain cycle?

Thanks

Comment: Don't think so, I've done this to animate self.view and it didn't do anything bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the  documentation , the animations block is defined as

"A block object containing the changes to commit to the views. This is where you programmatically change any animatable properties of the views in your view hierarchy."

So answer is no.